# How to pipe to bash as a different user

Tags: bash, software-installation, sudo, ruby

I am running an experiment as a way to solve a bigger problem. For the experiment, I need to install `rvm` as a user who does not have a shell.

To install rvm, you use the following command

`\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash`

How would I run the following command as a different user?

This is what I am attempting to do, but it does not work.

```
sudo -u foo -H \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash 
sudo -u foo -H which rvm  
sudo: rvm: command not found
```

Comment: any reason why you're asking about running stuff as a user, but your examples are using sudo's `-g` option to set the group rather than `-u` to specify the user?

Comment: Good point, the -g should be -u. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to run the shell as the user, not the `curl` or the `which` command.

There are several ways this can be done, including:

```
sudo -u user bash -c 'curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash'
```

and

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo -u user bash
```

If you want to do it interactively, you can use `sudo`'s `-s` option to override the fact that they don't have a valid shell.  For example:

```
# sudo -u user -s /bin/bash
$ whoami
user
$ exit
```